# can anyone explain about this XV6 inline asm validateint() test function that uses a pointer as ESP for a system call?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, inline-assembly, xv6

Hi~ I'm working on xv6 and I'm stuck on the validate test in `usertests.c`. There is asm code and I'm quite confused about what exactly is going on here. Would you like to explain that for me?

```
// try to crash the kernel by passing in a badly placed integer
void
validateint(int *p)
{
  int res;
  printf(stdout,"in validateint\n");
  asm("mov %%esp, %%ebx\n\t"
      "mov %3, %%esp\n\t"
      "int %2\n\t"
      "mov %%ebx, %%esp" :
      "=a" (res) :
      "a" (SYS_sleep), "n" (T_SYSCALL), "c" (p) :
      "ebx");
  printf(stdout,"%d \n",res);
}
```

I found that `res` is increasing with `p` but at some point `res` becomes 0 and then it becomes -1. The whole function stucks as long as `res` turn to -1. I have no idea what happened here.

Comment: Integer overflow?

Comment: @MadPhysicist That makes sense! so what os do if there is an overflow in kernal?

Comment: Judging by the comment, isn't this just a call to `SYS_sleep` that is meant to demonstrate that the kernel will (or will not) fault if its argument (`*p`) is an invalid pointer? The return values seems to confirm this (and that the kernel doesn't fault) but I don't understand what "as long as `res` turn to -1" means.

Comment: What's the point of asking for `p` in ECX with a `"c"` constraint?  What args does xv6's "sleep" system call take?  Linux follows POSIX and has `sleep(unsigned int seconds)` as a library function on top of nanosleep, for example.    (And where does xv6 want its args?  On the user-space stack, pointed to by ESP?  Or are EBX and ECX special, like they are for the Linux int 0x80 ABI?)

Answer (score 2):

From https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-public/blob/eeb7b415dbcb12cc362d0783e41c3d1f44066b17/syscall.c#L10 it appears that system call arguments are passed on the stack.  So the purpose of this code seems to be to invoke the system call with a possibly invalid stack, i.e. with the stack pointer containing some random address `p`.

I'd guess that the return value of 0 corresponds to when the stack is pointing to valid process memory, and -1 is returned when it is not.